# Create an object that has methods deferred to a different object for execution [Python]

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

To explain it and for simplicity, I will use the power domain example.
Imagine that you have more than one equipment. All plugged in one power strip with multiple plugs. The power strip can be controlled via an Ethernet or some other means. Out of all these,  there is ***one and only one*** which can actually turn power on and off. Nevertheless, I would like the rest of  equipment pieces to "appear" as being capable to control the power switch, as well. Programmatically, such functions can look something like:

```
pwr.poweron()  # this instance can do the actual poweron/poweroff via remote control
eq1.poweron()
eq2.poweron()
```

where `eq1, eq2` are instances of some class. `eq1 and eq2` just *appear* as being able to control the power. In reality, they defer  `poweron/poweroff` for execution to instance `pwr`. 
How would you design such class in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
class Pwr(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def poweron(self):
        pass

class Eqp(object):

    def __init__(self, pwr):
        self.pwr = pwr

    def poweron(self):
        self.pwr.poweron()

pwr = Pwr()
eq1 = Eqp(pwr)
eq2 = Eqp(pwr)
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! Another question would be to know how many equipment pieces were power controlled by `pwr`.

Comment: The `Pwr` class can provide `register_equipment` method that would be called from the `Eqp` constructor. The `pwr` object would know the precise number of registered `eqp`s at any moment.